# Search_in Super search

Tags: solspace, search, supersearch

I have a simple super search form and I want the results to only search in 2 custom fields, I don't want it to search titles or any of the other custom fields that I have in the channel. My code below shows you that in the results I have, per the poor documentation, used the search_in parameter but that is not limiting a search to those fields. When doing a search with a word from a title field, instead of seeing the "no results", it displays a result. What am I missing?

```
<form action="{path='/sync/ss_results'}" method="post" id="sc_search">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{csrf_token}" />
                <input type="text" name="tags-like" id="keywords" placeholder="Search" size="18" maxlength="100" />
                <input type="submit" id="search" value="search" />
            </form>

{exp:super_search:results channel="videos|series_head" search_in="bible_book_chapter|sh_scripture" redirect_post="no" exclude_entry_ids="29|30|31|33|34|35"}
{if super_search_no_results}Sorry we weren't able to find any videos listed under that passage.{/if}
    <div class="vid_opt" id="vid_opt{count}">
        <img src="{recent_video_thumb}{sh_recent_video_thumb}" alt="{Title}">
        <h3>{title}</h3>
         </div>
{/exp:super_search:results}
```

Comment: What version of Super Search and EE are you using? Please provide the exact version numbers. Also are the `bible_book_chapter` and `sh_scripture` fields set as searchable in EE? Also, any reason for using `redirect_post="no"`? Usually, setting this to "yes" allows for the search criteria to be shown in the URL, which is helpful.

Comment: EE 2.9.2, SS 2.2.2

Comment: EE 2.9.2, SS 2.2.2 Yes both fields are searchable. Those fields are Solspace Tag fields, if that makes a difference. This is the first step to getting what i actually need working. I will be making it submit with ajax.

Comment: No solution then?

Comment: Did you turn on the Output Profiler? If you clear the Super Search cache and look at the Output Profiler, you might see which queries are being run. Also, are you using fuzzy searching? Try turning that off: fuzzy searching can affect your results as words that would normally not pull results do with this on. If it still occurs, can you give a real-life search example, what you expect, and what you're getting instead?